# does `def main(args):` in python make sense?

Tags: python, coding-style

I see a lot of Python code that looks like this:

```
def do_something(arg):
    # some stuff

def do_something_else(arg):
    # some other stuff

def main(args):
    do_something(args.an_arg)
    do_something_else(args.another_arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    main(args)
```

I'm wondering why/whether it makes sense to define that `main` function. If the function `main` isn't intended to be imported from elsewhere, then this seems perfectly good:

```
def do_something(arg):
    # some stuff

def do_something_else(arg):
    # some other stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    do_something(args.an_arg)
    do_something_else(args.another_arg)
```

... and if it is intended to be imported from elsewhere, it should be given a more meaningful name (and accept arguments in the more usual fashion):

```
def do_something(arg):
    # some stuff

def do_something_else(arg):
    # some other stuff

def do_two_things(arg1, arg2):
    do_something(args.an_arg)
    do_something_else(args.another_arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    do_two_things(args.an_arg, args.another_arg)
```

Is this right? Does it make sense to define a `main` function like in the top example?

Comment: Making it a distinct function provides a fixed entry point, making it easier to test.

Comment: I do this all the time with modules created ad-hoc...and then add a `main2()`, or other names to test functionality out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... and if it is intended to be imported from elsewhere, it should be
>   given a more meaningful name (and accept arguments in the more usual
>   fashion)

The main reason to favor a generic name here like `main` is specifically to be generic: i.e., for polymorphism.

For example, let's say you have a bunch of modules you want to test which are designed to be executed standalone (not imported from other modules). But to test them, you want to use a python script to create a temp directory, fill it with generated files as test content, and then execute each of these modules in a generic kind of way without accounting for the unique differences of every single module you want to test this way.

To do this all in python, you would need these modules you want to test to have an identifier in common for all of their main entry point functions whether it's `main` or something else (the key is that it's the same for all modules to give them a uniform public interface). The names all of these functions have for their main entry point function has to be rather nondescript beyond the fact that the function is a main entry point into that module, since each module would have to export a function with an identical name as the next module beside it in order to allow such polymorphic code which depends on each module to provide a uniform public interface.

When polymorphism is needed in this sort of context whether it's for classes or modules, the most descriptive name we can use can't take into account too many specifics. It cannot take into account what each module is specifically doing, since it needs to be *uniform across modules*. In this particular case, we need an extremely generic name, and `main` is an extremely generic name.

As a result, one might favor a nondescript name here, not describing exactly what the function does but instead allowing a whole bunch of modules to provide functions with the same name so that they can all be uniformly used the same way by the exact same code.